# How to get the values of the table columns while adding the rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html

I have a table which can add up rows (insert row() method in js) when clicked on a button.

First column has a select tag which is populated with the product names from data base.  Second column has a input text box for quantity. Next is a button. When I click on the button it should multiply the price of the selected item from first column with the quantity and set the answer to the next column i.e price.
This is working for only one row. When I add new row and click the button for setting price, it will take the value of first row itself.

Comment: "insert row() method in js" seems like a reference to javascript `insertRow()` method. I suspect this question has nothing to do with [tag:mysql], [tag:sql] or [tag:database].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to add an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This all should be done on application level on client side with proper server side checks on submission. You shouldn't need database CRUD at this point.